# Preserve SVG Image-Link TCPDF/FPDI & Ghostscript

Tags: symfony, pdf, ghostscript, tcpdf

In my application I utilize TCPDF to create a PDF that pastes an SVG onto it with the `$link` being a url that is being provided by the user [so the SVG on the PDF is clickable](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_058/) like this

```
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, $pageLayout, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// remove default header/footer
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(0, 0);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(1);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
$fullPath = "$path".'qr-code/'."$uniqname".'.svg';
        
// Paste SVG onto page
$pdf->ImageSVG($file=$fullPath, $x=0, $y=0, $w='', $h='', $link=$query, $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=true);

/* Save as File */
$pdf->Output($path.'temp/'.$uniqname.'.pdf', 'F');
```

I then turn this PDF into a fully black CMYK PDF using Ghostscript

```
$targetFile = $path.'temp/'.$uniqname.'.pdf';
$iccFile = $this->params->get('ICC_FILE');
$process = new Process(['gs', '-o', $path.'pdf/'.$uniqname.'.pdf', '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', '-sColorConversionStrategy=Gray', '-dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray', '-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4', '-dOverrideICC=true', "-sDefaultCMYKProfile=$iccFile", $targetFile]);

$process->run();
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
```

And at the end I merge this PDF with another containing a Logo using FDPI like so

```
// create second PDF document for pasting logo
$pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Tcpdf\Fpdi(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, $pageLayout, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// remove default header/footer
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(1);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

/* Import fullHeight page */
$pages = $pdf->setSourceFile( $path.'pdf/'.$uniqname.'.pdf', 'F' );
$page = $pdf->ImportPage( 1 );
$pdf->useTemplate( $page, 0, 0 );

if($logoselect == 'eng')
{
    $logos = $pdf->setSourceFile( $path.'img/engadin_online_CMYK.pdf', 'F' );
    $logo = $pdf->ImportPage( 1 );
    $pdf->useTemplate( $logo, 34.25, 33.75, null, 32.5);
}

if($logoselect == 'gam')
{
    $logos = $pdf->setSourceFile( $path.'img/gammetermedia_CMYK.pdf', 'F' );
    $logo = $pdf->ImportPage( 1 );
    $pdf->useTemplate( $logo, 34.25, 33.75, null, 32.5);
}

// Close and output PDF document
$base = $pdf->Output('qrcode.pdf', 'E');
```

My problem now is that the link I created on the SVG of the first PDF is not in the last PDF anymore. Is there any way I can preserve this link so that it is still clickable in the last PDF or any other way I can achieve the same result?

As requested heres [the initial pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QlM0fAor7oTrFfeSq614HJodB7BHWACN/view?usp=sharing), [the ghostscript output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ixaWu3PytN36YXfmT1h5h3LGsFnLlIWU/view?usp=sharing), and [the final pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tVa3RZLkagTSRRX1pHTiLjwHwBCUIS9B/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @KJ unfortunately thats the problem why I am also asking for different approaches. I only know of the way of adding a hyperlink onto the svg like I did it now which has to happen obviously when I put the svg onto the page so I can't do it last. And the point of gs isn't merging the logo but instead converting the pdf that was created to a fully black cmyk pdf and the logo comes after cause the gs would make the logo black too

Comment: You can't put an SVG file into a PDF file (well you can, but not as part of the PDF exactly), so the 'hyperlink' must be represented in some other fashion, most probably a /LNK annotation. Ghostscript's PDF interpreter and pdfwrite device will preserve that, so if I understand what you are doing, it should work. Without seeing the original PDF file though, I can't be certain. I'm afraid the source code for TCPDF doesn't help me, I can't use that. If you post an example PDF then I might be able to help further. Ideally, the original PDF file, the output from pdfwrite and the final file.

Comment: @KenS ive attached the pdf files. hope it helps

Comment: @KenS oh and also as you can see the ghostscript preserves the link but its fpdi that cant preserve it after the logo is pasted

Comment: [That's](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/after-importing-a-page-all-links-and-annotations-are-gone/#question-84) the behavior of FPDI, sorry. We may add support for at least external links in the near future. Currently a workaround could be the use of e.g. our [SetaPDF-Stamper](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-stamper/details/) component to add the final logo. It modifies the original document and doesn't transforms the pages into xobjects as FPDI does.

Comment: I can see two possibilities; if the logo is a simple image you could write en EndPage procedure to draw it onto the page. Failing that it is possible to write a PostScript program which draws page 1 from a file, then without terminating the page, draw page 1 from a second file. That effectively draws the second page on top of the first (which I think is what you want). If you do that with the pdfwrite device selected, you'll get a PDF file out.

Comment: There is one additional possibility; if you know the URL and the size of the page, you could run the final PDF file through Ghostscript using the pdfwrite device, and add a pdfmark with a /Link annotation to put the final (hyperlink) annotation back in place. But I suspect that might be difficult to automate.

Comment: Hmm actually I see that the URL is known to you, and presumably you know the size of the image, so you could, as an additional final step after stamping the logo on, run the PDF file through Ghostscript using the pdfwrite device, and add a Link annotation pdfmark.

Comment: @KenS I couldn't really find anything helpful when searching for the link annotation pdfmark. could you maybe answer this post with a example code?

Comment: You need the Adobe pdfmark reference. You need to create a named destination and a reference to it, using PostScript. So "gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf input.pdf -c "[/Dest https://URL_GOES_HERE#MyNamedDest /Page 1 /DEST pdfmark [/Rect [0 0 34.25 33.75] /Dest /MyNamedDest /Subtype /Link /ANN pdfmark" -f" Something like that, anyway, I haven't actually tried this myself.

Comment: @KenS so did I understand this correct, I put the url then # and then give the destination a name and in the bak by /MyNamedDest I put that same name?

Comment: That seems to be what the pdfmark reference suggests yes. The '#' tells the interpreter that the value is a URL + name. You then reference the named object using just the name portion. As I said, I haven't actually tried this......